# Joomla Login Temporarily Disabled

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I use joomla 3.2. When log in to backend  I recived note: "Joomla Login Temporarily Disabled".
Please help me!

Comment: Can you access your database via phpmyadmin etc? Did you install any 3rd party extensions? Did you perform any updates/changes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sure to understand what do you need.
Do you need to login successfully(because now you didn't)?
Or do you need to enable the login form in frontend?

For now I can say you this, when you point to the index page transform it to this:

```
index.php?option=com_user&view=login
```

This should open a separate login page.

I hope this help you.

Bye....